# How to remove NEO4J from CE edition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j CE .. there are system and neo4j databases.

-bash-4.2$ neo4j --version
neo4j 4.3.2

I am facing startup the NEO4J database..

neo4j@system> show databases;
| name     | address                           | role         | requestedStatus | currentStatus | error                                                               | default | home  |
| "neo4j"  | "awsneodevldb01.est1933.com:7687" | "standalone" | "online"        | "offline"     | "An error occurred! Unable to start `DatabaseId{483e7f9b[neo4j]}`." | TRUE    | TRUE  |

1. how can I find out why unable to start NEO4J
2. how to remove it and create an empty ENO4J

Answer (score 0):

I recreate an empty ENO4J on CE. .. by ref. other post on this stackoverFlow.

1. stop neo4j
2. remove /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/neo4j
3. remove /var/lib/neo4j/data/transactions/neo4j
4. start neo4j

You have to remove the neo4j directory under transactions too.

Answer (score 0):

ref. you can find out why the neo4j database could not startup from following log file.

/var/log/neo4j/debug.log

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to start 'DatabaseId{483e7f9b[neo4j]}' since transaction logs were found, while database files are missing.